# mysql, use two select

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

why i get error:
Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
 SELECT name, cat_id,
    (
    SELECT topic
    FROM category
    WHERE cat = u.cat_id
    ) AS topics
    FROM name u
```

Thanks

Comment: Because it does? A subquery like this must return 1 row only.

Comment: You can use Top 1 in the sub select query which will result in returning only one row to your main query

Answer (score 3):

I have maybe a silly answer but why arent't you using a JOIN ?

```
SELECT name.cat_id, name.name, category.topic
FROM name INNER JOIN category 
ON category.cat = name.cat_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub-query:

```
SELECT topic
FROM category
WHERE cat = u.cat_id
```

Is returning more than one result - which you are trying to fit it into a single row.

Answer (score 0):

because you have two rows with the same cat (I assume it means category)

Answer (score 0):

You have more topics of that category ID.

Answer (score 0):

well, yes. It returns multiple rows in your case.
What do you want to have?

You can get 1 row if you add LIMIT 1 at the end of the subquery.
You can use JOIN if you want one additional row for each additional topic.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a subquery as a column, so it must return a single row. You could add LIMIT 0,1

Answer (score 0):

Because in your sub query you get **multiple rows of topic returned**.

And in **select part sub query such case is not allowed**.

Use **JOINS** if you expect multiple topic rows for user for category.

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the 2 tables

```
SELECT name.name, name.cat_id, category.topic
FROM name, category
WHERE name.cat_id = category.cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If your nested select query returns more than one, you can fetch only the first result by saying SELECT TOP 1 topic from category...